# How to find full service name from partial name in python

Tags: python

I am writing a Python script that will manage multiple Oracle databases on a single box. Each database has its own OracleService, but they all run under one TNSListener. Because each computer's install might name things differently I want to make this as dynamic as possible.

First, I need to start the TNSListener service. Most of these are on local laptops that only start the listener when we are going to use an Oracle database. In addition, some laptops run different versions of Oracle so the actual service name is different. For this I need to be able to find the full service name or names that contains the string 'TNSListener'.

Second, all of the OracleService names will be appended by the instance name (i.e., OracleServiceTESTING1). So I need to get a list of all the OracleServices on the machine and then display a selection of the instances based on the appended portion of the service names.

I thought about accessing the registry and trying to pull services from there, but the overhead to parse through that seems excessive. I'm just looking for some general guidance on how to find all services that match the string 'TNSListener' and 'OracleService'.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a library like [pywinservicemanager](https://pypi.org/project/pywinservicemanager/1.0.2/).  A short code example to check if a particular service exists would look like this:

```
from pywinservicemanager.WindowsServiceConfigurationManager import ServiceExists

serviceName = 'TestService'
serviceExists = ServiceExists(serviceName)
print serviceExists
```